# Can`t get Resources file by name in asp.net core

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, localization, resources, data-annotations

I've been trying to localize modelstate errors in asp.net core and found a solution with shared resorces file but it isn`t visible in the app as it was in the example. Resource's access is public. Please help.
[Here's the error and files hirerarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7PXE.png)

project: [project dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD4eb.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should modify the resource file from nocode generate to public, then it will generate the resx class to let you use.

Details, you could refer below image:

Example codes:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.SharedResourceSecond))]
```

[image]

Comment: As I said in my question I already done it and thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Could you please share your csproj file build-up?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "build-up" but hope it will help (edited question)

Comment: I mean the csproj file's content.  You could double click the csproj file and paste its xml format value.

Comment: Yeah, I added it to the question.